# Worker Role consuming a Session Partitioned Queue - MessageSessionHandler or AcceptMessageSessionAsync

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a Service Bus Queue with several sessions, that I use as way to enforce order per entity.

And I need a worker role to read messages from this Queue, and read messages from any session, in a way that when it's reading a message from a session no other instance of this role will get messages from that session.

What would be the best way to consume those, using a `MessageSessionClass` or having doing the `AcceptMessageSessionAsync` and `OnMessageAsync(messagehandler)`?

Having a hard time understanding which method would fit better in a worker role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure SDK 2.3 introduced support for session-awareness when using `OnMessageAsync`. See [sparse MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesessionasynchandler.aspx).

The gist is that you'll implement an `MessageSessionAsyncHandler` to handle the messages for a given session:

```
class MySessionHandler : MessageSessionAsyncHandler
{  
    protected override async Task OnMessageAsync(MessageSession session, BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        // Do the work here
    }
}
```

Then, you'll register that type with the queue client. You can specify how many sessions you want to concurrently process, among other options:

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    QueueClient client = ...;
    var options = new SessionHandlerOptions(){ MaxConcurrentSessions = 3 }
    client.RegisterSessionHandler(typeof(MySessionHandler), options);
}
```

Comment: John Hoerr, the link to OnMessageAsync usage is no longer valid

Comment: Thanks Richard. I couldn't find an updated version so linked to the MSDN docs instead. :\